# Ruby passing lots of args

Tags: ruby

I have a method that receives about 20 arguments, in that argument I would like to pass all those to another method.  Can I pass them all into the second method without retyping them all?  Is there an args array or something that I can pass?

What I have:

```
def my_method(arg1, arg2, ..., arg20)
  #do some stuff
  my_second_method(arg1, arg2, ..., arg20)
  #do other stuff
end
```

What I would like:

```
def my_method(arg1, arg2, ..., arg20)
  #do some stuff
  my_second_method(args[array])
  #do other stuff
end
```

Comment: I would strongly suggesting not having 20 arguments.

Comment: Anyone else smell something? Like a rotten eggs...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having a method that accepts that many arguments **[is a code smell](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TooManyParameters)**. This method is almost surely trying to do too many things with too many different kinds of data.

That said, if this is unavoidable, try this approach, using Ruby's splat operator.

```
  def one(*args)
    # process/validate args
    two(*args)     # Note that the splat is needed here too.
  end

  def two(*args)
    # do work
  end
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use Ruby's splat operator:

```
def my_method(*args)
    # do some stuff
    my_second_method(*args)
    # do other stuff
end

def my_second_method(*args)
    # use args[0] through args[19]
end
```

Comment: I think `my_second_method(args)` should be changed into `my_second_method(*args)` (if Ruby had pattern matching, then that [ie `my_second_method(args)`] would be possible:))

Answer (score 3):

So, this might not be the best idea, but having said that, you can use a hash to manage arguments.

Rails does this a lot:

```
render :partial => "new", :locals => {:object => @my_object}
```

Ruby's ActiveSupport has a way to deal with this, the `extract_options!` function, that is detailed on [simone carletti 's blog](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/09/inside-ruby-on-rails-extract_options-from-arrays/)

Comment: +1 with 20 arguments (if that is really required), an option hash is a great way to keep it readable.

Comment: ...or keyword parameters if you're using Ruby 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
def as_array(*args)
  if args.length == 3
    a, b, c = args
    puts "a=#{a} b=#{b} c=#{c}"
  end
end


as_array 1, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a common idiom that you can often see in Ruby code:

```
def method1(*args)
  method2(*args)
end

def method2(*args)
end

method1(a, b, c, d, e, f, g)
```

Notice how the **splat** operator is used. It basically first packs the args into an array, and then, on method call, unpacks it back into the individual arguments. It's very handy when you just need to pass the args further to another method, eg in an initializer.